# Rhino mock an abstract class w/o mocking its virtual method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, virtual, rhino-mocks, abstract

Can I execute the body of a virtual method that lives on an abstract class which has been mocked using Rhino Mocks?

To be clear, I'm not trying to mock the behavior of the virtual method.  I'm trying to /test/ the virtual method (on the mocked class).

Is this idea a blatant misuse of Rhino Mocks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that should be absolutely fine. I can't say I've tried it, but I'd be very surprised if it failed.

EDIT: I suspect you want the `PartialMock` method. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using Rhino.Mocks;

public abstract class Abstract
{
    public virtual int Foo()
    {
        return Bar() * 2;
    }

    public abstract int Bar();        
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MockRepository repository = new MockRepository();
        Abstract mock = repository.PartialMock<Abstract>();

        using (repository.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(mock.Bar()).Return(5);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(mock.Foo()); // Prints 10
    }
}
```

EDIT: Or in my first attempt at AAA:

```
using System;
using Rhino.Mocks;

public abstract class Abstract
{
    public virtual int Foo()
    {
        return Bar() * 2;
    }

    public abstract int Bar();        
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Arrange
        Abstract mock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<Abstract>();
        mock.Stub(action => action.Bar()).Return(5);

        // Act
        int result = mock.Foo();

        // Assert
        mock.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Bar());
        // And assert that result is 10...
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have been more clear in the question.  I've tried it plainly, and it doesn't work.  I was hoping someone would shed some light on how to test a virtual method that lives on an abstract class that's been instantiated using Rhino Mocks.

Comment: @lance: Yes, it would have been useful if you'd said that to start with... I'll try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @lance: I've posted an example which works for me... you may have a slightly harder time if your class isn't public or the abstract methods aren't public. I'm sure there are ways around this though - I haven't used Rhino for a while.

Comment: I'm using Rhino Mock's AAA syntax, and it's failing for me.  Are you able to repro success using the AAA syntax?

Comment: @lance: I haven't used the AAA style myself, but looking around it looks like it should be fine *if* you're happy with the stub behaviour for any abstract methods called by the virtual method you're calling. It sounds like you have rather more experience with the AAA approach than I do, so you're probably in a better place to experiment.

Comment: @lance: I've pieced together *an* of what I think the AAA syntax should look like - but it may well not be great...

Comment: You're using Rhino Mocks 3.6?

Comment: @lance: I just downloaded the latest version of Rhino.Mocks to write these examples. I haven't used it in anger for years...

Comment: I've just repro'd success using your code and Rhino Mocks 3.6 AAA. Rhino Mocks 3.5 AAA is behaving differently for me, but I'm content to solve this problem with an upgrade.  Thanks for the back and forth -- you've been incredibly helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Rhino.Mocks to call back to the original implementation instead of doing its default behavior of just intercepting the call:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<YourClass>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Foo()).CallOriginalMethod(OriginalCallOptions.NoExpectation);
```

Now you can call the `Foo()` method on your `mock` object.

Comment: I don't see the Setup method when generating the mock statically?

Comment: Hmmm... What version of Rhino.Mocks are you using?